# The overloading problem of generic classes

Tags: typescript

There is now a generic class `Graph<T>` whose constructor takes two arguments, `isDirected` and `primaryKey`. If the type passed in is an object type, `primaryKey` is required, otherwise it is not.
Is there any good way to solve this problem, important premise, that can't be solved at run time

For example:

```js
const graph = new Graph<{a:number}>(false) // type error: primaryKey required
const graph = new Graph<{a:number}>(false,'a') // nothing err
const graph = new Graph<number>(false) // nothing err
```